# Fast way to set diagonals of an (M x N x N) matrix? Einsum / n-dimensional fill_diagonal?

Tags: numpy, matrix, optimization, diagonal, numpy-einsum

I'm trying to write fast, optimized code based on matrices, and have recently discovered einsum as a tool for achieving significant speed-up.

Is it possible to use this to set the diagonals of a multidimensional array efficiently, or can it only return data?

In my problem, I'm trying to set the diagonals for an array of square matrices (shape: M x N x N) by summing the columns in each square (N x N) matrix.

My current (slow, loop-based) solution is:

```
# Build dummy array
dimx = 2  # Dimension x (likely to be < 100)
dimy = 3  # Dimension y (likely to be between 2 and 10)
M = np.random.randint(low=1, high=9, size=[dimx, dimy, dimy])

# Blank the diagonals so we can see the intended effect
np.fill_diagonal(M[0], 0)
np.fill_diagonal(M[1], 0)

# Compute diagonals based on summing columns
diags = np.einsum('ijk->ik', M)

# Set the diagonal for each matrix 
# THIS IS LOW. CAN IT BE IMPROVED?
for i in range(len(M)):
    np.fill_diagonal(M[i], diags[i])

# Print result   
M
```

Can this be improved at all please? It seems np.fill_diagonal doesn't accepted non-square matrices (hence forcing my loop based solution). Perhaps einsum can help here too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to reshape to `2D`, set the columns at steps of `ncols+1` with the diagonal values. Reshaping creates a view and as such allows us to directly access those diagonal positions. Thus, the implementation would be -

```
s0,s1,s2 = M.shape
M.reshape(s0,-1)[:,::s2+1] = diags
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Is there any further way to speed this up, to avoid doing numerous reshapes?

Comment: @PhysLQ Well, reshaping to create a view is the best way to have a viewed access to an array and reshape is virtually free. I don't see any other usage of reshape with the proposed method, or do we need reshapes elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you do `np.source(np.fill_diagonal)` you'll see that in the 2d case it uses a 'strided' approach

```
    if a.ndim == 2:
        step = a.shape[1] + 1
        end = a.shape[1] * a.shape[1]
    a.flat[:end:step] = val
```

`@Divakar's` solution applies this to your 3d case by 'flattening' on 2 dimensions.

You could sum the columns with `M.sum(axis=1)`.  Though I vaguely recall some timings that found that `einsum` was actually a bit faster.  `sum` is a little more conventional.

Someone has has asked for an ability to expand dimensions in `einsum`, but I don't think that will happen.

Comment: So, how does copying and pasting the source code for `np.fill_diagonal` help in improving upon it for faster diagonal filling?

Comment: My answer is more of a footnote to yours.