# how to set diagonal of volume of matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a volume of matrices, say `a = np.zeros((5, 7, 4, 4))`

I want to set the diagonal to some value, across all matrices.

Just like I can [get the diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) with `diag = np.diagonal(a, axis1=2, axis2=3)`, I would like to set the diagonal.

However, [np.fill_diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) does not support `axis=`.

How can I still achieve this?

Comment: Can you do it with loops, or are you looking for a built-in solution?

Comment: @ofey loops are no good for me.

Comment: `fill_diagonal` works on a 4d array.  Transpose your axes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
s1, s2, s3, s4 = a.shape
i, j = np.diag_indices(s3)  # s3 == s4 == 4 here.
a[..., i, j] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5, 7, 4, 4))
s0, s1, s2, s3 = a.shape

for index in range(s0):
    a[index].reshape(s1,-1)[:,::s3+1] = 3 # assign the diagonal values to 3
```

Taken from [fast way to set diagonals of an M x N x N matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43990116/8839623) with a little change. I believe this does what you want.

Edit: Aha. As @hpaulj's suggested, we can do it without a loop as you've desired.

```
a = np.zeros((5, 7, 4, 4))
s0, s1, s2, s3 = a.shape
a.reshape(s0 * s1, -1)[:,::s3+1] = 3 # assign the diagonal values to 3
```

Comment: you should be able to apply the linked answer to a 4d without the loop.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the idea. Just 'flattening' it even further works better :)